# Input object for GraphQL and TypeScript: at which point do I fill default values?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

So this is more of a design question.

I have an object called `Meaning` (basically a dictionary record), and an input object called `EntryMeaningInput`. (I called it that because `Entry` [the headword, basically] is a different entity, but it's not that important.)

The issues is this: for **creating** a `Meaning` I want the user to be able to only enter some fields, but not others (a partial object), and then fill them at some point (with empty strings); but for **updating**, I don't want it.

In `updateMeaning` (in the resolver), I could try to write:

```
@Arg("options", () => EntryMeaningInput) options: Partial<EntryMeaningInput>
```

But GraphQL doesn't understand `Partial<T>`.

For now, my input object looks like this (it looks like GraphQL picks them up from TS):

```
@InputType()
export class EntryMeaningInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  headword: string = "";

  @Field(() => String)
  definition: string = "";

  @Field(() => String)
  usage: string = "";

  @Field(() => String)
  imageLink: string = "";

  @Field(() => String)
  notes: string = "";
}
```

One solution would be to create two input types, one for creating and one for updating, but that seems a bit redundant.

I also know that Nest.js (which I'm not using for this app) has [the `PartialType` util](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/mapped-types):

```
@InputType()
export class UpdateUserInput extends PartialType(CreateUserInput) {}
```

What is the best (the most elegant?) way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

One popular approach would be to mark certain properties as nullable:

```js
@InputType()
export class EntryMeaningInput {
  @Field(() => String, {
    nullable: true,
  })
  headword?: string = "";

  @Field(() => String, {
    nullable: true,
  })
  definition?: string = "";

  @Field(() => String)
  usage: string = "";

  // snip
}
```

It eliminates the need of creating separate types for create and update mutations.

The downside is that you have less explicit API, which could result in API users don't including missing values when they are needed. This could be mitigated by JavaScript validation of input object in resolver or service.